# Load and unload different version of jar at runtime

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I am working with two different versions of a certain library. If the user chooses an object, I will recognize the libraries version, that created that object. Now I need to run code corresponding to that version.

The problem is, that code is redundant in both library versions, each version only valid for the objects that have been created with that version. I think, the consequence is, that I need to do the following at runtime:

- Unload the jars, that are not needed
- Load the jars, that are needed.

Is that possible by using the URLClassLoader? Somehow like this?

```
File dirVersion3= new File("lib/dirVersion3");
File dirVersion4= new File("lib/dirVersion4");
URL[] url={dirVersion4.toURL()};

ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(url, currentThreadClassLoader);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
```

Comment: is this a standalone java class or part of a utility deployed on an app server?

Comment: Basically if you create a new classloader for each library, you can have both versions available at the same time. If you load the same class with two different (peer) classloaders you will notice that a `ClassA` loaded by CL1 is not the same as `ClassA` loaded by CL2 as the CL is part of the class object loaded! What you can do is refactor the common code to a library that both JAR versions are using, load the common JAR with a common CL or the app CL and use this CL as parent for the version-specific CL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. Repackage one version of the library with jarjar (https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) so it gets different package names. This way you can load both versions in the same ClassLoader at the same time.
2. Create 2 ClassLoaders which load one library version each and write lots of delegation and reflection code